# Golang append changing append parameter

Tags: go

When running the following program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    edges := [][]int{{1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4}, {1,4}, {1,5}}
    printSlice2d(edges)

    _ = append(edges[:0], edges[1:]...)
    printSlice2d(edges)
}

func printSlice2d(s [][]int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

I get the following output:

```
len=5 cap=5 [[1 2] [2 3] [3 4] [1 4] [1 5]]
len=5 cap=5 [[2 3] [3 4] [1 4] [1 5] [1 5]]
```

I don't understand why edges is being changed by calling append. I would expect the first and second lines to be the same. I've checked the specification, but I can't seem to find anything that would explain this behaviour this kind of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice uses array internally to store the data.

`append` function does not create a new array if it is not necessary to increase array size beyond its current capacity. Instead it copies new data elements into existing array. After that function returns reference to a new slice that internally uses the same array.

You can read more in this article - https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

> As mentioned earlier, re-slicing a slice doesn't make a copy of the
>   underlying array. The full array will be kept in memory until it is no
>   longer referenced. Occasionally this can cause the program to hold all
>   the data in memory when only a small piece of it is needed.

This is what is going on in this line:

```
_ = append(edges[:0], edges[1:]...)
```

1. second `append` function argument (`edges[1:]...`) copies 4 items of `edges` into temp var. Its value - `[{2,3}, {3,4}, {1,4}, {1,5}]`
2. these values are copied into array that `edges` uses internally to store data. That overrides all items except of last one. This is where `edges` is mutated.
3. `append` returns reference to a new slice that internally uses the same array to store the data as `edges`
4. returned slice is ignored and will be garbage collected, but that does not matter for `edges`.

That is why you see changed values when you check `edges` after performing `append` on it.

Comment: Append doesn't return pointers. Array sizes are fixed, so it can't "increase [the] size of current array". It will indeed allocate a new array if the underlying array is too small to fit the values that are to be appended. That's all described in the blog post you linked.

Comment: @pete thanks for your comment. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`edges[:0]` is a slice of length 0 starting at index 0 of the underlying array of `edges`.

To this slice, you append another slice, the slice of length 4 starting at index `of the underlying array of`edges`. That gives you the first 4 elements of the result you see in the second line.

Then you print `edges`, which is a slice with an underlying array of 5 elements, whose last 4 you just shifted one element lower. The last element is duplicated. in the `edges` array.

If you look at the result of the `append`, then you'd see a slice with length 4, cap 5, the first 4 elements of the underlying array of `edges`.

If you expected the two lines to be the same, maybe you tried to do:

```
append(edges[:1],edges[1:]...)
```