# Why appending on slice modified another slice?

Tags: go

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    src := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    a := src[:3]
    b := src[3:]
    a = append(a, 9)

    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

output:

> [0 1 2 9] [9 4 5 6]

Did append modified the underlay array as  []int{0, 1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6}?
Slice a was copied as a new slice with a new underlay array with value [0, 1, 2, 9] and slice b still pointing to the old array that was modified.

Thanks for any hints, much appreciated

Comment: Does `go vet` complain?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17395261/12258482, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59596644/5728991, and many more

Comment: `append` does allocate new underlying array only if the old one has no sufficient capacity. Otherwise it assigns the value at the position instead.

Comment: Read this answer: [Concatenate two slices in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248241/concatenate-two-slices-in-go/40036950#40036950).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Slice a was copied as a new slice with a new underlay array with value [0, 1, 2, 9] and slice b still pointing to the old array that was modified.

> - `a := src[:3]` created a slice (a pointer to the src head, length=3, capacity=7)
> - `b := src[3:]` created a slice(a pointer to the src[3],length=4, capacity=4)
> - `a` and `b` shares the same memory created by `src`
> - `a = append(a, 9)`,when appending to the same slice, as long as it does **not exceed cap**, it is the same array that is modified

- Did append modified the underlay array as []int{0, 1, 2, 9, 4, 5, 6}

> YES

If the `append` exceed the `cap` of `a`, new array will be allocated and data will be copied the the new array

try this out:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    src := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    a := src[:3]
    b := src[3:]
    a = append(a, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)

    fmt.Println(a, b)
}
```

Output:

> [0 1 2 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9] [3 4 5 6]